# Compilation failure when using std::shared_ptr instead of boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio, shared-ptr, boost-bind

The code below successfully sends an async message to the given endpoint.

```
// message is a boost::shared_ptr<std::string>

// open a UDP socket
boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket(ioService);
socket.open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4());

// create the remote endpoint
boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint remoteEndpoint(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string(address), port);

// asynchronously send a datagram to the remote endpoint
socket.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(*message),
                     remoteEndpoint,
                     boost::bind(&MyClass::handler,
                                 this,
                                 message,
                                 boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                 boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

socket.close();
```

However, if I change the type of `message` to a `std::shared_ptr<std::string>` rather than a `boost::shared_ptr<std::string>` then the call to `async_send_to` doesn't compile.

The error is:

```
boost/boost/bind/bind.hpp:457:9: No matching function for call to object of type 'boost::_mfi::mf3<void, MyClass, const boost::shared_ptr<std::__1::basic_string<char> > &, const boost::system::error_code &, unsigned long>'.
```

Can someone explain what is wrong? Is it possibly because I'm using boost::bind?

Comment: What is the protype of `MyClass::handler`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like problem is, that you `handler` function receives `boost::shared_ptr`, not `std::shared_ptr` and `boost::shared_ptr` is not constructible from `std::shared_ptr`.